# Restore primefaces documentViewer after page reload

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using documentViewer-component from primefaces-extensions like this:

```
<pe:documentViewer cache="true" value="#{myBean.streamedContent}"/>
```

myBean is SessionScoped.

If I reload the page the getter is called and the streamedContent is not empty, but the viewer shows an empty page and the message `stream must have data`.

How can I restore the document in the viewer on page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem using [PrimeFaces Extensions Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf), so I used below code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

Document document = new Document();  
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);  
document.open();  

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  
      document.add(new Paragraph("All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy"));  
}  

document.close();  
content = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()), "application/pdf");
```

But I've found a solution. Problem exists only using `DefaultStreamedContent` but when I've checked the hierarchy I've found that there is also posibility to use `ByteArrayContent`. It works even after page reloading.

Sample usage:

```
content = new ByteArrayContent(out.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
```